# Relationship between Q Studentized range and Student distributions

Tags: tukey-hsd-test

I was looking at the article about Tukey test on Wikipedia regarding the relationship between Q Studentized range and Student distributions and it look like

$\sqrt{2}  t(1 - \alpha / 2, n-c)  =  Q(\alpha, c, n-c)$

for $c$ groups and $n$ total observations ( t- Student critical value).
Is there a way I can check this formula formally? I cannot find any resource where the details would be shown.